# jquery change input serialization format

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I got a table with similar input names, which i'll use to generate array and save in backend using php and ajax. The problem is whenever i serialize the input it generates array in different format than what i want as you can see below. How can i change it?

```
         <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Product</th>
                    <th scope="col">quantity</th>
                    <th scope="col">rate</th>
                    <th scope="col">total</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="items">
                <tr>
                    <td><input form="itemForm" type="text" class="form-control" name="product[]" required /></td>
                    <td><input form="itemForm" type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity[]" value="0.00" required /></td>
                    <td><input form="itemForm" type="text" class="form-control" name="rate[]" value="0.00" required /></td>
                    <td><input form="itemForm" type="text" class="form-control" name="total[]" value="0.00" required /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input form="itemForm" type="text" class="form-control" name="product[]" required /></td>
                    <td><input form="itemForm" type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity[]" value="0.00" required /></td>
                    <td><input form="itemForm" type="text" class="form-control" name="rate[]" value="0.00" required /></td>
                    <td><input form="itemForm" type="text" class="form-control" name="total[]" value="0.00" required /></td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

This is the php output:

```
Array
(
 [product] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    )

 [quantity] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0.00
        [1] => 0.00
    )

 [rate] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0.00
        [1] => 0.00
    )

 [total] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0.00
        [1] => 0.00
    )

 )
```

This is the format i want:

```
Array (
 0 => 
  Array (
  'product' => 'product 1',
  'quantity' => 0.0,
  'rate' => 0.00,
  'total' => 0.00
 ),
 1 => 
  Array (
  'product' => 'product 2',
  'quantity' => 0.0,
  'rate' => 0.00,
  'total' => 0.00
 ),
)
```

Comment: You cannot change the way it works, but you can process the first array into the second. But there is no magic bullet you will have to write some code, or snag some from the internet

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer according to your query, it can achieve the expected output this way. But this can also be achieved dynamically (better approach), just need to loop your rows. where I have used "0" in "0[product]", "1" in "1[product]" you have to pass the pointer respectively.

```html
   <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Product</th>
                    <th scope="col">quantity</th>
                    <th scope="col">rate</th>
                    <th scope="col">total</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="items">
                <tr>
                    <td><input form="itemForm" type="text" class="form-control" name="0[product]" required /></td>
                    <td><input form="itemForm" type="text" class="form-control" name="0[quantity]" value="0.00" required /></td>
                    <td><input form="itemForm" type="text" class="form-control" name="0[rate]" value="0.00" required /></td>
                    <td><input form="itemForm" type="text" class="form-control" name="0[total]" value="0.00" required /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input form="itemForm" type="text" class="form-control" name="1[product]" required /></td>
                    <td><input form="itemForm" type="text" class="form-control" name="1[quantity]" value="0.00" required /></td>
                    <td><input form="itemForm" type="text" class="form-control" name="1[rate]" value="0.00" required /></td>
                    <td><input form="itemForm" type="text" class="form-control" name="1[total]" value="0.00" required /></td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
```